# Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 512, 512, 3), found shape=(512, 512, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, image-segmentation

I am training a Unet segmentation model for binary class. The dataset is loaded in tensorflow data pipeline. The images are in (512, 512, 3) shape, masks are in (512, 512, 1) shape. The model expects the input in (512, 512, 3) shape. But I am getting the following error.
Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 512, 512, 3), found shape=(512, 512, 3)

Here are the images in metadata dataframe.

[image: Metadata Dataframe]

Randomly sampling the indices to select the training and validation set

```
num_samples = train_metadata.shape[0]
train_indices = np.random.choice(range(num_samples), int(num_samples * 0.8), replace=False)

valid_indices = list(set(range(num_samples)) - set(train_indices))

train_samples = train_metadata.iloc[train_indices, ]
valid_samples = train_metadata.iloc[valid_indices, ]
```

Dimensions

```
IMG_WIDTH = 512
IMG_HEIGHT = 512
IMG_CHANNELS = 3
```

Parsing function for training images

```
def parse_function_train_images(image_path):
    image_path = image_path
    mask_path = tf.strings.regex_replace(image_path, "sat", "mask")
    mask_path = tf.strings.regex_replace(mask_path, "jpg", "png")

    image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.uint8)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT))
    #image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

    mask = tf.io.read_file(mask_path)
    mask = tf.image.decode_png(mask, channels=1)
    mask = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(mask, tf.uint8)
    mask = tf.image.resize(mask, (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT))
    #mask = tf.where(mask == 255, np.dtype("uint8").type(0), mask)

    return image, mask
```

Parsing function for test images

```
def parse_function_test_images(image_path):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.uint8)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT))
    #image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

    return image
```

Loading the dataset

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_samples["sat_with_path"].values)
train_dataset = ds.map(parse_function_train_images)

validation_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(valid_samples["sat_with_path"].values)
validation_dataset = validation_ds.map(parse_function_train_images)

test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test_metadata["sat_with_path"].values)
test_dataset = test_ds.map(parse_function_test_images)
```

Normalizing the images

```
def normalize(image, mask):
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0
    mask  = tf.cast(mask, tf.float32) / 255.0
    return image, mask

def test_normalize(image):
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0
    return image

TRAIN_LENGTH = len(train_dataset)
BATCH_SIZE = 64
BUFFER_SIZE = 1000
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = TRAIN_LENGTH // BATCH_SIZE
```

Mapping the dataset

```
train_images = train_dataset.map(normalize, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
validation_images = validation_dataset.map(normalize, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
test_images = test_dataset.map(test_normalize, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Augmentation Layer

```
class Augment(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, seed=42):
        super().__init__()
        self.augment_inputs = tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip(mode="horizontal", seed=seed)
        self.augment_labels = tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip(mode="horizontal", seed=seed)

    def call(self, inputs, labels):
        inputs = self.augment_inputs(inputs)
        inputs = tf.expand_dims(inputs, axis=0)
        labels = self.augment_labels(labels)
    
        return inputs, labels

train_batches = (
    train_images
        .cache()
        .shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
        .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
        .repeat()
        .map(Augment())
        .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
)

validation_batches = (
    validation_images
        .cache()
        .shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
        .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
        .repeat()
        .map(Augment())
        .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
)

test_batches = test_images.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

Unet Model

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_CHANNELS))
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(inputs)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c1)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c1)

p1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1)

c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(p1)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c2)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c2)

p2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c2)

c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(p2)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c3)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c3)

p3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c3)

c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(p3)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c4)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c4)

p4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c4)

c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(p4)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(c5)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c5)

u6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(c5)
u6 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u6, c4])

c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(u6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c6)

u7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(c6)
u7 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u7, c3])

c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(u7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c7)

u8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(c7)
u8 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u8, c2])

c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(u8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c8)

u9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(c8)
u9 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)

c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(u9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c9)

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation="sigmoid")(c9)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()

checkpointer = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('model_for_nuclie.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=2, monitor="val_loss"),
    tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir="logs"),
    checkpointer
]
```

Fit the model to data

```
results = model.fit(train_images, validation_data=validation_images, \
                batch_size=16, epochs=25, callbacks=callbacks
        )
```

Error:

[image: Error]

Comment: Can you show the shape of one batch from `train_batches`?

Comment: for images, masks in train_batches.take(2):
    sample_imaDge, sample_mask = images[0], masks[0]
    print(sample_image.shape)
    #display([sample_image, sample_mask])

Comment: (64, 512, 512, 3)
(64, 512, 512, 3)

Comment: @AloneTogether using train_batches.take(2) and printing the shapes.

Comment: Use `train_batches` in `model.fit` and not `train_images`..

Comment: When providing an infinite dataset, you must specify the number of steps to run (if you did not intend to create an infinite dataset, make sure to not call `repeat()` on the dataset). 

That's the error I see now.

Comment: Why are you using `repeat()`? Remove that

Comment: Okay. That seems to work.

Comment: ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 256, 256, 1) vs (None, 512, 512, 1)).

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `train_batches` in `model.fit` and not `train_images`. Also, you do not need to use `repeat()`, which causes an infinite dataset if you do not specify how many times you want to repeat your dataset. Regarding your labels error, try rewriting your model like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((512, 512, 3))
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(inputs)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c1)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c1)

p1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1)

c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(p1)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c2)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c2)

p2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c2)

c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(p2)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c3)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c3)

p3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c3)

c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(p3)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c4)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c4)

p4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c4)

c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(p4)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(c5)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c5)

u6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(c5)
u6 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u6, c4])

c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(u6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c6)

u7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(c6)
u7 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u7, c3])

c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(u7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c7)

u8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(c7)
u8 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u8, c2])

c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(u8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(c8)

u9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(c8)
u9 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation="sigmoid")(u9)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()
```